# Asp.Net Core 2 Razor AddPageRoute : How to pass id or other information into Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to pass in information into my Page Model via the page route:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/News?handler=Pageid&id=10", "News/2018/Jan");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/News?handler=Pageid&id=11", "News/2018/Feb");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/News?handler=Pageid&id=12", "News/2018/Mar");
```

I have a corresponding method:

```
public void OnGetPageid(int id) {
```

But this approach does not work - the page is blank - does anyone know how I can accomplish this in a simple and straightforward way? This does work:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/News", "News/2018/Apr");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/News", "News/2018/May");
```

But no Model-specific info is passed in

Comment: Have you add route in `startup.cs` file?

Comment: Hi Ekrad, I understand more about Core MVC now and instead have implemented a middleware component that rewrites the incoming path to match a custom controller. Thanks